# Control animation with scroll in swift? Is it possible?

Tags: swift, animation, scroll, uiscrollview

Alright, so I've done things like this in jquery but I really need to achieve the effect in Swift for iOS -

I need my Uiview animation to occur incrementally (I.e with the scroll, so they scroll fast the animation happens really fast, slow the animation goes slow, stop, etc) controlled by a scroll in a scroll view.

Think the open slide bar on an iPhone. I haven't found any questions on this in swift and the closest I've found Is this obj c link- http://www.oliverfoggin.com/controlling-animations-with-a-uiscrollview/

And I have no idea how to apply this to my animation. This is my animation that occurs on touch here with this rect-

self.activeBorder = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.activeBorder.backgroundColor = kDefaultActiveColor
    //self.activeBorder.backgroundColor = kDefaultActiveBorderColor
    self.activeBorder.layer.opacity = 0
    self.addSubview(self.activeBorder)

and animating using:

```
self.borderlines.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.01), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
self.activeBorder.layer.opacity = 1

CATransaction.begin()
self.activeBorder.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.03), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
let anim2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
let fromTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(0.01), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
let toTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(1.0), CGFloat(1.0), 1)
anim2.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: fromTransform)
anim2.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: toTransform)
anim2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
anim2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
anim2.removedOnCompletion = false
self.activeBorder.layer.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: "_activeBorder")

CATransaction.commit()
```

This makes a rectangle grow out from the center as a line/border. I need this to be controlled by a users scroll
Ina scroll view.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this? I know very little about obj c- can I transfer this code to my animation even though it isn't related to the color animation discussed in the tutorial?